# Getting Duplicate Spree Route (without custom routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to use out-of-the-box spree routes, but I'm running up against an error that prevents me from migrating my database or precompiling my assets for Heroku:

> rake aborted! ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use:
> 'account_link'  You may have defined two routes with the same name
> using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already
> defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can
> restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

My routes can be seen below, but I'm not doing any custom spree routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # This line mounts Spree's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to URLs such as /products, will go to
  # Spree::ProductsController.
  # If you would like to change where this engine is mounted, simply change the
  # :at option to something different.
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Spree relies on it being
  # the default of "spree".
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  #  COSMETICS
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'

  get 'home/info'
  get 'home/export'
  get 'home/kits'

  get 'kits/XR250_XR400'
  get 'kits/XR600'
  get 'kits/XR650L'
  get 'kits/polaris_key_covers'
  get 'kits/replacement'
  get 'kits/rear_fenders_1'
  get 'kits/rear_fenders_2'
  get 'kits/graphics'

  get 'other/xr400mx'

  # PHOTOS
  resources :photos
  put "photos/:id/approve" => "photos#approve", as: "approve_photo"
  put "photos/:id/unapprove" => "photos#unapprove", as: "unapprove_photo"

  # CONTACT US
  resources :contacts
  put "contacts/:id/archive" => "contacts#archive", as: "archive_contact"
  put "contacts/:id/unarchive" => "contacts#unarchive", as: "unarchive_contact"

  get 'admin/blogs'
  post 'uploader/image', to: 'uploader#image'
  get 'admin/resources'
  get 'admin/subcategories'
  get 'admin/subscribers'
  resources :blogs
  resources :lead_magnets
  resources :subscribers
  resources :subcategories

  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/store', as: 'spree'

end
```

When I try to push to Heroku it shows the error is somewhere inside railties?

> remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile remote:
> DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated.
> Template handlers must remote:        now accept two parameters, the
> view object and the source for the view object. remote:        Change:
> remote:          >> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template)
> remote:        To: remote:          >>
> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template, source) remote:
> (called from  at /tmp/build_3e42be0e/Rakefile:6) remote:
> rake aborted! remote:        ArgumentError: Invalid route name,
> already in use: 'account_link'  remote:        You may have defined
> two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be
> overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.
> For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources`
> as explained here:  remote:
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
> remote:
> /tmp/build_3e42be0e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:578:in
> `add_route'

I am seriously out of my depth here.  Please help!

I'm running these spree-related gems:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.6'
```

Comment: Are there any spree routes in the output of `rake routes` ?

Comment: @RockwellRice The error prevents any output of `rake routes` from appearing, so I'm kind of flying blind.  :(

Comment: What versions of those gems are you using exactly (look in your Gemfile.lock file)?  I looked in the git repo for the spree gem and found that route defined but not in the latest versions of the other two Gems.  What I would do is look in the repos, make sure it is on your version of the gem (which could be a branch or a tag) and try to find that route.  The fix could be as simple as just bumping the version up or down one.

Comment: Also, is it possible there is another Gem that could have a link like that/. If you don't find one in the Spree Gems I would look in other Gems that could have a related route.  Once you find it just check the next version up until you see it gone.  If it is in the Spree Gems I would assume they figured it out pretty quickly and fixed it.